# insert object to set c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have this following fucntion to handle points (among a set of points) whose type is Start_Vertex:

```
void handleStartVertex(Vertex vi)
{

    cout << "start Vertex begins ######################################################################################" << endl;
    cout << "Handling start " << vi << vertexType[vi.type] <<  endl;
    HalfEdge *ei = vi.incidentEdge;
    std :: vector<HalfEdge > :: iterator it,itprev;
    cout << "Origin of the incident Edge " << *(ei->origin) << endl;
    //INSERT EI IN TOW AND SET HELPER AS VI
    ei->setHelper(&vi);
    tow.push_back(*ei);

    cout << "Content of Tow in START_VERTEX" << endl;
    for(it = tow.begin();it != tow.end();it++)
        cout << "origin of edge " << *((*it).origin) << " Helper "  << *((*it).helper) << endl;
    cout << "start Vertex stops ######################################################################################\n\n" << endl;
}
```

where tow is :

```
vector<HalfEdge >  tow;
```

The problem is when I am setting the helper of an Edge and pushing it into vector tow,for all edges previously present in tow, the helper changes to that of the edge being presently pushed. I am not understanding why is this happening? Any work around is appreciated. Here are some results which can make the question more clear.

---

start Vertex begins ###########################################################################
Handling start  (2,9) START_VERTEX
Origin of the incident Edge  (2,9)

Content of Tow in START_VERTEX

origin of edge  (6,12) 
 Helper  (2,9)

origin of edge  (9,11) 
 Helper  (2,9)

origin of edge  (2,9) 
 Helper  (2,9)

start Vertex stops ############################################################################

The correct result I should be getting is: 

origin of edge (6,12) Helper (6,12)

origin of edge (9,11) Helper (9,11)

origin of edge (2,9) Helper (2,9)

Comment: Do comment if anything is not clear..

Answer (score 0):

The Vertex vi is destroyed at the return of the function. You are setting the helper to the memory occupied by Vertex vi, and this memory is occupied by Vertex (2, 9) when you do the last print. Pass a pointer to the Vertex vi as input to the function:

```
void handleStartVertex(Vertex* vi)
{
...
}
```